# Ошибка - Program1.pas(2) : Встречено 'Uses', а ожидалось ';'

Tags: pascal, .net, pascalabc.net

Возможно глупый вопрос для большинства людей тут. У меня как у человека, который начал только познавать программирование возникла некоторая проблема при написании кода в PascalAbс.NET.

Собственно, ошибка:

> Program1.pas(2) : Встречено 'Uses', а ожидалось ';'

Мой код:

```
Program cikl
Uses GraphABC;
 Var
r:Integer;
begin
 for r:=460 downto 100 do
  begin
    circle(620,480,r);
    r:=r-35;
  end;
 FloodFill(170,480,clPurple);
 FloodFill(205,480,clBlue);
 FloodFill(240,480,clSkyBlue);
 FloodFill(275,480,clGreen);
 FloodFill(310,480,clYellow);
 FloodFill(345,480,clLime);
 FloodFill(380,480,clMoneyGreen);
 FloodFill(415,480,clRed);
 FloodFill(450,480,clMaroon);
 FloodFill(485,480,clBrown);
 FloodFill(620,480,clNavy);
End.
```

Заранее спасибо. Если не сложно не только исправить, но объяснить в чём она была.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

где то точку с запятой забыли. 
И отформатируйте текст, выделите код и нажмите ctrl+k

```
Program cikl; // судя по ошибке проблема тут, если я не все еще забыл
Uses GraphABC;
 Var
r:Integer;
begin
 for r:=460 downto 100 do
  begin
    circle(620,480,r);
    r:=r-35;
  end;
 FloodFill(170,480,clPurple);
 FloodFill(205,480,clBlue);
 FloodFill(240,480,clSkyBlue);
 FloodFill(275,480,clGreen);
 FloodFill(310,480,clYellow);
 FloodFill(345,480,clLime);
 FloodFill(380,480,clMoneyGreen);
 FloodFill(415,480,clRed);
 FloodFill(450,480,clMaroon);
 FloodFill(485,480,clBrown);
 FloodFill(620,480,clNavy);
End.
```

Comment: Упс , спасибо . Нужно быть внимательнее.
Хотя сейчас выдало новую ошибку , Program1.pas(9) : Нельзя изменять значение переменной цикла внутри этого цикла.
в строке с r:=r-35 .

Comment: @Maximilliano задайте переменную вне условия цикла, на строку выше, например - должно помочь.

Comment: @Maximilliano , про переменную в цикле создайте отдельный вопрос, если проблема еще не решена.

Comment: Нет , всё решено , галочку вроде как поставил.